# Kotlin type mismatch, generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

I found a strange behavior in kotlin. Given this code :

```
interface Animal

class Owl : Animal

class Page<T>(var list: List<T>)


fun ok(): List<Animal> {
    val list = listOf(
            Owl()
    )

    return list
}

fun error(): Page<Animal>  {
    val list = listOf(
            Owl()
    )

    val page: Page<Owl> = Page(list)

    return page
}
```

Owl implements Animal. The first function compiles, but on the second one, I've got the error :

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Page<Animal>
Found: Page<Owl>
```

I don't understand why kotlin can't do the type inference and guess that a `Page<Owl>` is also a `Page<Animal>`.

Can someone give me tips on this, and possibly some workaround ?

Comment: The type parameter to `Page` is invariant. You have to add `out` to its type parameter to make it covariant: `class Page<out T>(var list: List<T>)`.

Comment: And `List` is already defined as having a covariant type in its declaration. So `List<Animal>` means exactly the same thing as `List<out Animal>`. That's why it works with List.

Comment: But it can't be covariant because of `list`'s setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the error() function returns invariant Page<Animal>, so it must be a Page<Animal> object: not a Page<Owl> one. You should add `out` to the generic to get it covariant, so the fixed implementation is:

```kotlin
fun error(): Page<out Animal>  {
    val list = listOf(
        Owl()
    )

    val page: Page<Owl> = Page(list)

    return page
}
```